# Typescript error I don't understand in my promise wrapper

Tags: typescript, promise, compiler-errors

Why can't I just return the promise by chaining then & catch, i don't see the difference here.

```
type SuccessResponse<T> = [T, null]

type ErrorResponse<U> = [null, U]

type Result<T, U> = Promise<SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse<U>>

export const promiseWrapper = async <T, U extends Error>(
  promise: Promise<T>
): Result<T, U> => {

  // --- This works ---
  try {
    const data = await promise
    return Promise.resolve([data, null])
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.resolve([null, error])
  }
  // ---


  // --- Doing this instead cause TypeScript error ---

  // return promise
  //   .then((data) => [data, null])
  //   .catch((error) => Promise.resolve([null, error]))
  // ---

}
```

This is the error i got. I read it as the promise i return not considered the "then & catch" chain in some way. And by doing it with by async/await (The working way) and decouple the promise the compiler understand that i want to return the Result<> promise?

If i want to use the promise chain how can I tell typescript that my promise will return Result<>?

```
Type '(T | null)[] | [null, any]' is not assignable to type 'SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse<U>'.
  Type '(T | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse<U>'.
    Type '(T | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'ErrorResponse<U>'.
      Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

Comment: Sort of side-note but your result seems odd. You've seem to taken the success/error callback style and put it as a tuple result in a promise. Whereas I'd expect the error to be the rejection of the promise. If you really want both, seems like you're after an `Either` which does make more sense but I'm not sure a tuple in a promise is the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript somehow cannot distinguish `[T, null]` from `(T|null)[]`. The value `[data, null]` is correct for both cases.

To solve the issue, it seems that you need to specify the type that is being returned by the `.then`:

```
  return promise
    .then<SuccessResponse<T>>((data) => [data, null])
    .catch((error) => [null, error]);
```

Comment: It works but why must i do this, and only for the SucessResponse? Where does ```(T|null)[]´´´ comes from?

Comment: Typescript tries to infer what `[data, null]` mean and ends up with `(T|null)[]`. This type is an array of elements that can be either T or null. When comparing `(T|null)[]` with your type `[T, null]`, it will not match.

Comment: I just found out now that there is another solution to help Typescript infer the tuple type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Basically, you need to set your types as readonly `type SuccessResponse<T> = readonly [T, null];` and `type ErrorResponse<U> = readonly [null, U];`, then you can do `.then((data) => [data, null] as const)` and `.catch((error) => [null, error] as const)`.